# Square of Elementary Matrix Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, inverse

I'm having trouble proving the following statement:

"There exists an elementary matrix $E_1$ such that $E_1^2 = I$"

I'm thinking about how the inverse of $E_1$ is equal to $E_1$ (so $E_1^{-1} = E_1$) but I'm not sure how to show the product of it, if that is even the right step towards the proof. 
Could someone help me out?

Comment: You mean, besides the identity? $I^2=I$

Answer (score 3):

Forget matrices. An elementary matrix "does something" - multiplying by $E$ swaps two rows or multiplies a row by a constant or adds a multiple of this row to that row.

Now think about finding one of those somethings with this property: If you do it twice you get back to where you started...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** In order to prove that such a matrix exists, find an example. Try to think of a row-operation that, when applied twice (in a row), gives you what you started with.

Comment: oh! If I multiply a row by -1 twice then I get back what I started with...

Comment: That definitely works. Do you know how to find the matrix that represents this row-operation?

Comment: You could also swap any two rows